# How to put the navbar-brand on the left and ul navbar-pills li on the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is from bootstrap and i can't figure out how to put the navbar-brand on the left and ul navbar-pills on the right of the page. please help. thanks in advance

```
<div class="page-wrap">

<div class="navmenu">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#index">
             <img alt="Brand" src="brand.png">
          </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>

</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how bootstrap works but alone you can use the float properties. So it would look like this in your css file

```
.navbar{
    float:left;
}
.nav-pills{
    float:right;
}
```

If you've already implemented bootstrap and this doesn't work you'd need to look in bootstraps api for information. This does work with jquery though

Comment: Are you using bootstrap already and what did using it give you

Comment: yeah using from getbootstrap.com

Comment: Have you looked at the bootstrap Api

Comment: I haven't worked with bootstrap but I believe it splits things into rows and columns so yeah

Comment: i'll wait for someone knows more about it then. tnx tho